Putting transformed classes into target/classes, get "Source must refer to an existing file" error from spring-boot repackage goal
We maintain a large number of SpringBoot services built with Maven. Many of these services have dependencies that contain only JAXB classes, used for marshalling and unmarshalling XML. These were all generated using the "javax" packages.  We are now upgrading to SpringBoot 3, which now requires the "jakarta" packages.
Eventually, the source code of those dependencies will be converted, but that will not happen quickly. In the meantime, we are trying to use the Eclipse "transformer-maven-plugin" to do the conversion. This plugin is conceptually straightforward, but there is one aspect that presented some difficulties. I initially couldn't figure out how to convert the dependencies so that the converted classes would be available at compile time. Without that, some code in the service fails to compile.
I eventually figured out that I can run the transformer plugin in the "generate-sources" phase, and then use "maven-antrun-plugin" to extract the transformed jars into "target/classes". When I do this, all the compile errors are resolved.
However, after the compile phase, when the "repackage" goal of the spring-boot-maven-plugin runs, it fails with an error like this:
Failed to execute goal org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:3.2.5:repackage (default) on project ...:
Execution default of goal org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:3.2.5:repackage failed:
Source must refer to an existing file, got C:\...\target\classes

I've never seen this error message before. The reference to "target/classes" at the end makes it pretty certain this is related to what I did with the transformer plugin.
I keep wondering whether there's a different solution to the "missing link" for the transformer plugin. Dumping the converted classes into target/classes BEFORE the compile phase seemed odd to me, but I found that it did work, at least for the compile phase. Is there a better way to make those converted classes available at compile time, besides putting them into target/classes?
Here are some excerpts of what I've done.
This is a portion of the transformer plugin definition:
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.eclipse.transformer</groupId>
    <artifactId>transformer-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
    <extensions>true</extensions>
    <configuration>
        <attach>false</attach>
        <buildDirectory>${project.build.directory}/transformed</buildDirectory>
        <rules>
            <jakartaDefaults>true</jakartaDefaults>
        </rules>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>thing</id>
            <phase>generate-sources</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>jar</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <artifact>
                    <groupId>...</groupId>
                    <artifactId>thing</artifactId>
                    <version>1.0.55</version>
                    <type>jar</type>
                </artifact>
                <baseName>thing</baseName>
            </configuration>
        </execution>

There are several execution blocks for each of the several dependencies that need to be converted.
This is an excerpt of the antrun plugin definition, which extracts the jars into target/classes:
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.8</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>prepare</id>
            <phase>process-resources</phase>
            <configuration>
                <target>
                    <unzip src="${project.build.directory}/transformed/thing.jar" dest="${project.build.directory}/classes"/>
                </target>
            </configuration>
            <goals>
                <goal>run</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>

This is our current definition of the spring-boot-maven-plugin:
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>3.2.5</version>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <goals>
        <goal>repackage</goal>
      </goals>
      <configuration>
        <classifier>fat</classifier>
        <layout>ZIP</layout>
        <includeSystemScope>true</includeSystemScope>
      </configuration>
    </execution>
  </executions>
  <configuration>
    <layout>ZIP</layout>
    <includeSystemScope>true</includeSystemScope>
  </configuration>
</plugin>


I think I'd try to split the problem into two. Have you considered transforming the dependencies once and publishing them somewhere? The consuming services could then be updated to use the already-transformed dependencies  and you wouldn't have to solve a combined transformation and packaging problem.

In fact, I've concluded that that is the only practical strategy, but it has its own drawbacks. I've given up on the fully automated approach, as can be seen by my struggles here. The drawback of the "two-step" approach is that each one of those has to be manually transformed (even with scripting support) and deployed. My "platform" team is likely going to be responsible for doing that for likely dozens of artifacts, for use by other development teams. It's not great, but probably the best balance of tradeoffs. The original strategy, even if I could get it to work, would have been complicated.
